# Analytics tool for .Net winforms application

Tags: windows, c#, .net, analytics, vb.net

Anyone can recommend a tool similar to Google Analytics that we can add to our .Net Winforms app? What we need to to understand how our users use our application. Logs like click counts, time, and patterns is what we would like to know.